# How to join table to itself when it references to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, self-join

I have table which have two columns which references to itself.

```
select * from cgroups;                                                                                                                                          
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | title        | description | cunixperm | cgroup_1 | cgroup_2 |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1  | admin        | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 2  | tag_mng      | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 3  | tags         | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 4  | exam_mng     | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 5  | exam_writer  | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 6  | exam_viewer  | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
| 7  | exam_starter | <null>      | 32        | 1        | <null>   |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

here is its code:-

```
create table cgroups
(
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    title varchar(100) not null unique,
    description varchar(255),

    cunixperm  tinyint unsigned not null default 32 ,# r=2 w=1
    cgroup_1   int unsigned not null default 1 references cgroups (id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    cgroup_2   int unsigned references cgroups (id) on delete cascade on update cascade

);
```

I want to create views in which cgroup_1 column is replaced with actual title of of c_group

something like this:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af382/1

```
select c.id, c.title, c.description, c.cunixperm, c1.title cgroup_1 from cgroups c , cgroups c1 
                             where c.cgroup_1 = c1.id;                                                                                                                                       
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| id | title        | description | cunixperm | cgroup_1 |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | admin        | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 2  | tag_mng      | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 3  | tags         | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 4  | exam_mng     | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 5  | exam_writer  | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 6  | exam_viewer  | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
| 7  | exam_starter | <null>      | 32        | admin    |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

problem with this approach is that it only works with 1 refereed column while I have two ( 8 in some other tables)

if I do following ,

```
select c.id, c.title, c.description, c.cunixperm, c1.title, c2.title 
from cgroups c , cgroups c1, cgroups c2
where c.cgroup_1 = c1.id and c.cgroup_2 = c2.id;
```

I get zero rows.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af382/4

Comment: Start by using a proper `JOIN` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your fiddle seems work; anyway you should use explicit join syntax:

```
select c.id, c.title, c.description, c.cunixperm, c1.title, c.cgroup_1 
from cgroups c 
INNER JOIN cgroups c1  ON c.cgroup_1 = c1.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af382/3

and for two join

```
select c.id, c.title, c.description, c.cunixperm, c1.title, c.cgroup_1 , c2.title cgroup_2
from cgroups c 
INNER JOIN cgroups c1  ON c.cgroup_1 = c1.id
INNER JOIN cgroups c2  ON c.cgroup_2 = c2.id
```

Comment: looks like my link confused you. I edited question. sorry for that. It only shows 1 referenced column but I need both referenced columns.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af382/4

Comment: thanks. it worked just added another  INNER JOIN clause

Answer (score 0):

By modifying caisEdge, Answer have it working:-

```
 select c.id, c.title, c.description, c.cunixperm, c1.title cgroup_1 , c2.title cgroup_2 
 from cgroups c  
 INNER JOIN cgroups c1  ON c.cgroup_1 = c1.id 
 INNER JOIN cgroups c2  ON c.cgroup_2 = c2.id;
```